# Open embedded Excel in Visio with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, visio

I have a little problem with VBA. I have about 800 Visio files with an embedded Excel, which if you double click, opens in a separate application.

The code in the Excel file has some errors/problems with Visio2007 / Excel2007. I already wrote the code for updating the Excel VBA code.

My problem is that I have to let the code run when the embedded Excel is opened, before any buttons are pressed!

I just need to know how I can open the embedded Excel with code! (I didn't find that anywhere..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening the embedded Excel document (and showing if required) should work with the following VBA code

```
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.OLEObjects.Count
    If Left(ActiveDocument.OLEObjects(i).ProgID, 11) = "Excel.Sheet" Then
        ActiveDocument.OLEObjects(i).Object.Activate
        ActiveDocument.OLEObjects(i).Object.Application.Visible = True
        ActiveDocument.OLEObjects(i).Object.Windows(1).Visible = True
    End If
Next i
```